# BlackBerry - Invoke a click event on bitmap Field

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, custom-controls

can anyone help me for solving the below question.
I am making an application for blackberry in that from one bitmapField i have to invoke a new screen by clicking on the bitmapField. I want the code for the same... how to invoke a new screen by clicking on a bitmapField... and i am using blackberry JDE 4.7

Answer (score 4):

Try making the BitmapField focusable

```
BitmapField bm = new BitmapField(bitmap, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE);
```

[This](http://blackberry-tips-bikas.blogspot.com/2009/08/clickable-bitmapfield.html) might help

Answer (score 2):

```java
BitmapField bmpField = new BitmapField(bitmap, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE)

   protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
   {
      if(bmpField.isFocus)
      {
          UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyScreen());
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

i have used on a Storm and it works.

If even this does not work, u can go ahead and use `touchEvent` instead of `navigationClick`

Answer (score 1):

This must work

```java
BitmapField bmpField = new BitmapField(bitmap, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE){

   protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on){
      //the simplies way to draw a rectangle and this will be the focus
   }                               

   protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
   {
      //write here your code what you want to run the user clicks to the bitmap
      //try something like this
      UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyScreen());
      return true;
   }
}
```