# Make a BitmapField go full screen when clicked

Tags: blackberry, java-me, fullscreen, bitmapfield

I am writing an app that does live streaming. Can I make a bitmap field go full screen when clicked?

Comment: If you want to read the images from RssFile,Initially read the RssFile and display the images in a GridView and finally display the single image from Gridview(if you click on an image from GridView) to a new Screen.

Comment: I am doing live streaming images from an ip camera. I just need to put up a click event that will make the bitmap field go on full screen.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it (that I could think of in 2 minutes):

- Make your bitmap clickable (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145163/blackberry-invoke-a-click-event-on-bitmap-field))
- When the bitmap field is clicked, scale it into a new bitmap the size of the whole screen:

`Bitmap scaled = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());`
`originalBitmap.scaleInto(scaled);`

- Create a new Screen, containing only a BitmapField (with your scaled bitmap)
- Push the new Screen.

Comment: How do i create a new screen? for this? should i extend the main screen?

Comment: You can also use a MainScreen object directly, without extending: screen = new MainScreen() and then screen.add(bitmapField).